# How to combine two columns from different tables that have a similar name but have different values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables (*example*) `STAFF, STU, EMP`.

[image: tables]

I want to combine the column `EMPID` in table `STAFF` and table `EMP` into 1 column?

My previous query is like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM STU s 
FULL OUTER JOIN STAFF st ON st.STAFFID = STUID 
FULL OUTER JOIN EMP e ON s.STUID = st.EMPID
```

The result is like this

[image: Result]

The expected result is just like the above screenshot, but I want to join **EMPID** into one column only.

**UPDATE**:

I tried using this query:

```
SELECT 
    stu.stuid, stu.stuname, stu.stucode,
    s.staffid, s.staffname, s.staffcode,
    emp.empname, emp.empcode, 
    COALESCE (emp.empid, staff.staffid) AS col
FROM 
    STU, Staff, EMP 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    STAFF s ON s.STAFFID = stu.STUID
FULL OUTER JOIN  
    EMP e ON stu.STUID = s.EMPID
```

but it displays an error like this

[image: error]

Comment: List the columns that you want in the `SELECT`.  Don't use `SELECT *`.

Comment: If I list all the columns, should I list both emp.empid and staff.empid or choose either one?

Comment: . . You would use `coalesce()`.

Comment: I try to use coalesce() but there's another error said "The multi-part identifier "stu.STUID" could not be bound" @GordonLinoff

Comment: @Ken - You can use the below query I have provided. I have modified your query to get the desired result. please try and let me know

Comment: @MukeshArora It works! Thank you so muchhh :D

Comment: @ken You are welcome. Please accept this solution below if it is work for you. This will help others to identify the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below query to get the desired result.

```
SELECT s.StuID, s.StuName, s.Stucode, st.StaffId, st.StaffName, st.Staffcode, isnull(st.EmpId, e.EmpId) EmpId, e.EmpCode, e.EmpName
FROM STU s FULL outer JOIN
     STAFF st
     ON st.STAFFID = STUID FULL OUTER JOIN
     EMP e
     ON s.STUID = st.EMPID
```

**Note:** You will get the one emp Id column as needed. If Staff emp id is not null then staff emp id will be displayed else employee emp id will be displayed